# Marketing Cloud SDK iOS, sfmc_getAllMessages

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Trying to use this method `sfmc_getAllMessages` from [this article](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/inbox/inbox.html), but it always returns nil.

I have also tried invoking the `refreshMessages` method and that always return NO.

I am testing this by sending a push/inbox message through MobilePush and have confirmed that I receive the push alert. How can I get the `sfmc_getAllMessages` to return the list of inbox messages?

Here is output from sfmc_getSDKState, replaced sensitive info with blank field

SDK State = {
  "MarketingCloud Connection Details" : {
    "Active AccessToken(Masked)" : "",
    "Active AppId" : ""
  },
  "Analytics Details" : {
    "PIAnalyticsEnabled" : false,
    "ETAnalyticsEnabled" : true
  },
  "Push Details" : {
    "Device has Push Enabled" : "Yes",
    "Device Token" : ""
  },
  "MarketingCloud SDK Features" : {
    "Enabled by Configuration" : "ETAnalytics, Inbox"
  },
  "Privacy Settings" : {
    "Privacy Mode" : "SFMCPrivacyModeNotBlocked"
  },
  "Device Specific Details" : {
    "OS Version" : "11.4",
    "Hardware Description" : "iPhone10,3",
    "Device Reported Timezone" : "-18000",
    "Device Locale" : "en_US",
    "DeviceId" : "",
    "Daylight Savings Time Active" : true,
    "Platform Name" : "iOS"
  }
}

Comment: You can make the query from the command line to test the response without the SDK by replacing `ACCESS_TOKEN`, `APPLICATION_ID` & `DEVICE_ID` in the following command: `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" -H Content-Type:"application/json" -H Accept:"application/json" -X GET https://consumer.exacttargetapis.com/device/v1/APPLICATION_ID/message/\?deviceid\=DEVICE_ID\&messagetype\=8\&contenttype\=2 -d "{}"`  The result should be your visible list of messages from the Marketing Cloud servers.

Comment: If you get an empty list of messages `{}` from that call then the SDK is not receiving the messages from the server and you should verify message start/end dates, addressee lists, etc.  You can find your `DEVICE_ID` in the Registration payload.

Comment: Yes it is returning this: {"count":0,"page":0,"pageSize":0,"links":{},"messages":[]}. We had this working with version 4.9 of Marketing Cloud SDK iOS and successfully retrieving inbox messages. I am pretty sure we are using the correct start/end dates and address list since I am receiving the push notification, the sdk is still returning nil when calling sfmc_getAllMessages

Comment: Now I am seeing messages when using the curl api call, but the sdk still returning nothing

Comment: Which version of the 5.x SDK are you using?

Comment: using version 5.2.0,

    `NSArray *etMessages = [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_getAllMessages];`

Comment: Thank you.  I've reached out to my counterparts on the iOS SDK team.

Comment: Could you call sfmc_setDebugLoggingEnabled:YES after you configure the SDK, and then capture the console log output for us? You'd be looking for messages starting with "inboxmessage". Messages are fetched from the server when the app comes to the foreground, and if/when you call sfmc_refreshMessages (see MarketingCloudSDK+InboxMessages.h for details).

Comment: Everytime I execute refreshMessages it returns NO, I do not see anything in the console output related to that after that is called. The only message I see is when I call that method twice in 60 seconds, "[foundation] Requesting inbox messages too frequently. Wait 60 seconds between requests for best results."

Comment: I am implementing the getAllMessages for a Cordova application, I was wondering why the SFMC Cordova plugin (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin) doesn't have the methods implemented for getAllMessages, refreshMessage, etc..

Comment: @BillMote Did you ever hear back from the iOS SDK Team on this issue?

Comment: You have asked this question again and I'm following that thread.  You are engaged with the iOS team both here and there.