# MC-Cordova-Plugin

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush

I am working on implementing the MC-Cordova-Plugin (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin) for iOS/Android and noticed the plugin does not implement any methods for interacting with inbox messages. I have tried to implement the methods for retrieving inbox messages on iOS using `sfmc_getAllMessages` but have had no luck getting it to return anything but nil. Has anyone successfully implemented inbox methods for iOS?

This is my post from before [Marketing Cloud SDK iOS, sfmc_getAllMessages](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225587/marketing-cloud-sdk-ios-sfmc-getallmessages)

`SDK State = {
  "MarketingCloud Connection Details" : {
    "Active AccessToken(Masked)" : "",
    "Active AppId" : ""
  },
  "Analytics Details" : {
    "PIAnalyticsEnabled" : false,
    "ETAnalyticsEnabled" : true
  },
  "Push Details" : {
    "Device has Push Enabled" : "Yes",
    "Device Token" : ""
  },
  "MarketingCloud SDK Features" : {
    "Enabled by Configuration" : "ETAnalytics, Inbox"
  },
  "Privacy Settings" : {
    "Privacy Mode" : "SFMCPrivacyModeNotBlocked"
  },
  "Device Specific Details" : {
    "OS Version" : "12.0",
    "Hardware Description" : "iPhone10,3",
    "Device Reported Timezone" : "-18000",
    "Device Locale" : "en_US",
    "DeviceId" : "",
    "Daylight Savings Time Active" : true,
    "Platform Name" : "iOS"
  }
}`

Comment: Did you set inbox to enabled in the SDK configuration as well?

Comment: Yes I did, I edited the original question to show the sdk state that is printing out and it displays the Inbox is enabled by configuration, have you had any success implement inbox methods?

Comment: I am able to receive push alerts just fine and use the exacttarget api to retrieve the inbox messages that had been sent to my device

Comment: I would have thought that sfmc_getAllMessages would just be calling the api under the covers, and also still confused why the inbox methods are not implemented for the cordova plugin

Answer (score 0):

The Cordova plugin does not support the full range of functionality offered by the native SDK - it is limited to basic push handling only, along with the required registration setters and getters.

As it is only calling into the SDK via the relatively thin "bridge", you should be able to implement inbox functionality without any problem, as you are describing. Calling sfmc_getAllMessages will return the array of messages in the system's inbox for your device.

If you enable debug logging in the SDK, you'll get a wealth of data recorded - look for "inbox" in those messages to understand the lifecycle and data.

Comment: I have tried to enable debug logging and that has not helped at all, everytime I call smfc_refreshMessages it returns NO and smfc_getAllMessages returns nil, do you have any other suggestions to try based on the SDK State from above

Comment: So my real question is has anyone had any success implementing the inbox methods for iOS? And I still find it weird that the plugin doesn't support all functionality, is everyone who is building a Cordova based app expected to implement the inbox methods

Comment: Also based on this https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/trouble/ios-debugging.html, the SDK State should be displaying details about the inbox

`"Inbox Details" : {
    "Count of All Inbox Messages in DB" : 0,
    "Count of Read Inbox Messages in DB" : 0,
    "Count of Unread Inbox Messages in DB" : 0
  }`

Comment: The only other thing that I have seen in the console output that is concerning is a bunch of Boring SSL Handshake Errors

`[BoringSSL] boringssl_session_errorlog(224) [C24.1:2][0x106706d50] [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_SSL(1): operation failed within the library

[BoringSSL] boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(205) [C22.1:2][0x153b08da0] 5699030728:error:100000d7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSL_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-109.200.32/ssl/ssl_lib.cc:1081:`

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts or assistance around this?

Comment: Still having issues with getting inbox messages on version 6.1.4 for iOS. Does anyone have any advice on to resolve this?